# ステータスバーの背景色、文字色について

Tags: javascript, ios, monaca, html5

Monacaでハイブリッドアプリの作成に挑戦している者です。
現在はiPadにて動作検証をおこなっているのですが、そこでステータスバーの表示について悩んでいます。
アプリの背景色は白のため、ステータスバーの文字（時刻や電池残量、電波状況など）は黒字で表示して欲しいのです。
iPad上のMonacaデバッガーで見ると、ステータスバーの文字は黒いのですが、iOS用にアプリをビルドし（デバッグビルド）、iPadにインストールすると、ステータスバーの文字色が白くなってしまい、アプリの背景色と同化して見えなくなってしまいます。

現在の設定等は以下の通りです。

- 端末：iPad Air(iOS 7.1.1)
- Cordovaプラグイン「Status Bar(org.apache.cordova.statusbar) v0.1.9」が有効。
- MonacaApp-Info.plist は

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<false/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

- アプリが読み込むjsファイルに`window.StatusBar.statusBarStyleDefault();`を記載。
  その場所を通っていることは確認済み。

設定の悪い箇所や、どうやれば出来るのか教えていただければ幸いです。
ご教授の程、どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 設定画面のCordovaバージョンはいくつでしょうか？また、使用しているデバッガーのバージョンはいくつでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
Cordovaのバージョンは4.1.0です。
使用しているデバッガーは「Cordovaバージョン：4.1.0」「Platformバージョン：3.7.0」です。

Comment: デバッガーでは、組み込みのプラグインでプラグインがデバッグされています。そのデバッガーにステータスバープラグインが組み込まれていないため、デバッガーとビルドアプリでの違いが発生しています。(また、Cordovaプラグイン設定画面にて有効にしたプラグインをデバッガーに入れたい場合は、ヘッダーメニューのデバッガーを選択して、カスタムデバッガーというものを作成する必要があります。)

Comment: デバッガーにどのプラグインが組み込まれているかを確認したい場合は、サイドメニューの「このデバッガーについて」をクリックすると見れますので、確認してみてください。

Comment: なるほど。デバッガーとビルドアプリの違いはそういった訳だったのですね。ありがとうございます。
試しに、[設定]>[Cordovaプラグインの管理]からStatusBarのプラグインを削除し、アプリをビルドしてみましたが、ビルドアプリのステータスバーの文字は白いままでした。
どう設定すればビルドアプリのステータスバーの文字は黒くなるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらく、古いドキュメントを読まれているのだと思います。`window.StatusBar.statusBarStyleDefault();`というのは古い書き方で、cordova3.5以降は`window.StatusBar.styleDefault();`と書きます。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます！
修正したところ期待していた動き（表示）になりました。